# What fields need to be on Gift Aid declaration form to avoid uncaught exception?

Tags: wordpress, gift-aid-extension

We're running Wordpress 4.9.7, CiviCRM 5.2.2, and UK GiftAid extension 3.0.1 from compucorp.co.uk. The previous extension version had a single field ('UK Tax Payer?') to add to the donation form and worked OK. As of version 3 the donation form is throwing an uncaught exception indicating that additional fields need to be on the form. Including all 8 new gift aid fields does work, but ends up duplicating address fields and making the form rather unwieldy.

Is anyone else using the new Gift Aid extension successfully? How can the process be made as simple as possible when integrated with an existing donation form?

Comment: Should have added that the configuration page is helpful but not sufficient. In particular it says "Note: make sure there is no duplicated in fields in the form you are asking people to complete i.e name and address fields." but it's not clear whether the GA address fields are considered duplicates with the contact address, or how they are populated.  The doc also does not give sufficient info to get the necessary scheduled job running under Wordpress. https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/

Comment: Eric - also trying to install on WordPress. Didn't work at all when I tried last year, but now looks basically OK. I'm using 3.0.1 which is later than the two you were trying. My main problem right now is that the documentation is very Drupal specific (paths for example) and a bit sparse. Maybe between us we can improve it and make it suitable for WP?

Comment: Mick, 3.0.1 also solved the uncaught exceptions. I've left it disabled however as we're not actually using GA at present, just experimenting. It's too high a hurdle for a tiny voluntary outfit at present and I'm afraid I can't put the time in. Be good if there was more WP info though...

Comment: Eric, fully understand the problems of time! I will try and persist with it and see if I can find time to produce some WP notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you miss out required fields it should show you an user-freindly error, not throw an exception. It should also indicate what fields are required. So whether or not the required fields have been entered, this is a bug in the gift aid module.

You can raise it with the developers of the gift aid module. They have an active issues queue here https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/issues

Regarding scheduled jobs - did you get it working? If so, I recommend updating their documentation and issuing a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for advice and the GitHub approach must be right. If only it was worth our while pursuing it. For now I think it must be considered only for Drupal users.

Comment: What do you mean? All it takes is checking their Github page to see if anyone has already reported the same issue, and if not, logging one yourself! You may need to make an account on Github, but all in all it will take you about 10 minutes!